# Error Sendmail-base

Tags: upgrade, sendmail

After upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10, my laptop error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up sendmail-base (8.15.2-11) ...
Saving current /etc/mail/sendmail.mc,cf to /var/backups
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: error: --group is only relevant with --add
dpkg: error processing package sendmail-base (--configure):
 installed sendmail-base package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sendmail-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
nocturnal@nocturnal-Linux:~$
```

If I write `sudo-apt get upgrade` or any way in the terminal.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instruction of one user that has commented at [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sendmail/+bug/1792582) forum.

Only Replace:

```
update-inetd --group MAIL --disable smtp,smtps,submission;
```

with:

```
update-inetd --disable smtp,smtps,submission;
```

in file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/sendmail-base.prerm`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @J.Demand for your answer

i also replace

```
update-inetd --group MAIL --multi --disable smtp,smtps,submission;
```

with

```
update-inetd --multi --disable smtp,smtps,submission;
```

in Directory

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/sendmail-base.postinst
```

this is works. thanks